# How open text file by default with UTF-8 endcoding system?

Tags: microsoft-windows, character-encoding

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10

In my init.el:

```
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
```

But when I open text file the Emacs not show correct Cyrillic text.
[image]

Why?

```
describe-variable -> buffer-file-coding-system
```

show that file is encoded in `utf-8-dos`

Comment: As a temporary fix, try `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system` and choose "utf-8".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add `(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)` after `(set-language-environment "UTF-8")`? Here is a reference for dealing with Unicode http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_n_unicode.html. Take a look at the section **How to set default file encoding?**.

Comment: Not help. Same result.